# How to prevent accidental execution of potentially harmful commands (e.g. reboot)

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh

I spend a lot of time in Terminal.app, and in iTerm2 - mostly using SSH connections to some Linux boxes. I'm used to issuing `reboot` commands to these Linux boxes, but earlier this evening I accidentally entered `sudo reboot` from Terminal.app that applied to my Mac. As a result, I've lost some of my Firefox history - maybe other things that I've not discovered yet.

I know how to "fix this" on a Linux box, but cannot get to first base on my macOS Ventura. I tried this:

```shell
seamus@Fumier-Pro ~ % whereis reboot
reboot: /sbin/reboot /usr/share/man/man8/reboot.8
seamus@Fumier-Pro ~ % cd /sbin
seamus@Fumier-Pro /sbin ~ % sudo mv reboot r-reboot
mv: rename reboot to r-reboot: Operation not permitted
seamus@Fumier-Pro /sbin ~ % GRRRRRRRR!
```

And so I guess this means that "`/sbin/reboot`" is in one of the read only partitions/volumes??

At any rate - How can I get to `reboot` to rename it - or maybe replace it with a simple script that has an `echo "Do you REALLY want to do this?"`?

Comment: The answers below are good. I'd like to note is that: you can't rename something in `/sbin` - it's a "feature" called System Integrity Protection. However, as environments are (along with `argv[..]`) part of what's passed to executing programs, they can be changed and set arbitrarily.

Comment: Also, even on Linux, it's not recommended to change anything directly managed by the distro. See [DontBreakDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian), I remember someone posting this link for a CentOS answer as well.

Comment: For Linux, there's a package called `molly-guard` that stops accidental shutdowns/reboots. I found a [MacOS port on github](https://github.com/raimue/molly-guard), but that one hasn't been update for 11 years, and I'm afraid it won't work on modern MacOS. Perhaps there's a more recent piece of software that does this?

Comment: @marcelm as that is just a script it should still work. It is just a prettified version of the reboot shell script as in the answers. Unix hasn't changed somethings in the last 30 years.

Comment: Frame challenge: I believe it's good practice for your normal user account _not_ to have `sudo` rights.  On my Mac, for example, I have a separate ‘admin’ account I can `su` to, and my sudoers file allows _that_ account to use `sudo`, but not my normal account.  In such a setup, you don't need special precautions against accidentally rebooting — or doing anything else dangerous — because `sudo` simply refuses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just create a `reboot` command in `/usr/local/bin`, which should come first in your `$PATH`.

Comment: That's a good solution - thanks... but is $PATH something that I (as a user/customer of Apple products) have control over?  By that I mean if they (Apple) place significant chunks of the filesystem out of my reach - might they not also play with the `env` variables?

Comment: They could, but putting /usr/local/bin in front is pretty standard, and it would be perverse for Apple to change this. Software like Homebrew depend on it.

Comment: The default PATH is built from `/etc/paths` which has `/usr/local/bin` first (which makes sense, because shadowing default binaries is one of the purposes of having `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: @Seamus don't forget that your interactions with the terminal emulator are largely through your chosen shell: you can always prepend something to PATH in your shell config.

Answer (score 10):

Springboarding from [@Seamus's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469272/how-to-rename-a-binary-in-sbin/469295#469295):

You could just add the following function to your `~/.zshrc` file.

```
sudo() {
    case "${1:-}" in
    reboot)
        echo "Are you REALLY sure you want to do this?"
        echo "If so, enter 'sudo r-reboot', and I'll pass it along.";;
    r-reboot)
        shift
        command sudo reboot "$@";;
    *)
        command sudo "$@"
    esac
}
```

Note the following.

- The built-in `command` command makes it unnecessary to know where the `sudo` command is located.
- Functions take precedence over commands, so you do not have to worry about what is in `PATH`.
- You do not have to add anything to `/opt/local/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.
- The function only applies to your account. Other users will not encounter any changes.

Answer (score 3):

Springboarding from [@benwiggy's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469276/40457):

1. Create a small script - `reboot` :

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "Are you REALLY sure you want to do this?"
   echo "If so, enter 'sudo r-reboot', and I'll pass it along."
   ```
2. Mark `reboot` as executable:

   ```sh
   chmod 755 reboot
   ```
3. Make a symbolic link:

   ```sh
   ln -s /sbin/reboot r-reboot
   ```
4. Check your PATH environment variable, and NOTE where `/sbin` lies:

   ```sh
   echo $PATH
   # in my case:
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------YYYYYY--------------
   /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
   ```
5. "Figure out" a dir that is NOT in Apple's  read-only file system. For example, I now know (*from the accepted answer*) that `usr/local/bin` is NOT, and I know that `/opt/local/bin` is NOT. With that information, copy as follows:

   ```sh
   sudo cp -a r-reboot reboot /opt/local/bin
   # and for good measure:
   sudo cp -a r-reboot reboot /usr/local/bin
   ```
6. Test

   ```sh
   % sudo reboot
   Are you REALLY sure you want to do this?
   If so, enter 'sudo r-reboot', and I'll pass it along.
   %
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to learn not to do this is exemplified by the `sl` package on a bunch of linux distros.  `sl` is a sometimes typo for `ls` and instead of being helpful, it gives you a steam locomotive in text mode that rolls across your terminal, and is **uninterruptible**.  Thus every time you typo, you must spent ~5 seconds watching this:

```
                          (  ) (@@) ( )  (@)  ()    @@    O     @     O     @      O
                     (@@@)
                 (    )
              (@@@@)

            (   )
           ====        ________                ___________
       _D _|  |_______/        \__I_I_____===__|_________|
        |(_)---  |   H\________/ |   |        =|___ ___|      _________________
        /     |  |   H  |  |     |   |         ||_| |_||     _|                \_____A
       |      |  |   H  |__--------------------| [___] |   =|                        |
       | ________|___H__/__|_____/[][]~\_______|       |   -|                        |
       |/ |   |-----------I_____I [][] []  D   |=======|____|________________________|_
     __/ =| o |=-O=====O=====O=====O \ ____Y___________|__|__________________________|_
      |/-=|___|=    ||    ||    ||    |_____/~\___/          |_D__D__D_|  |_D__D__D_|
       \_/      \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/      \_/               \_/   \_/    \_/   \_/
```

This brief annoyance is enough to help "re**train**" you without being a full-on safety net.

`alias reboot="echo Local reboot penalty...;nohup sleep 5  > /dev/null ; echo then run /usr/sbin/reboot instead"`

Test this by running `which reboot`

```
user@host ~ % which reboot
reboot: aliased to echo Local reboot penalty...;nohup sleep 5;echo then run /u\n......etc
```

---

The problem with this is that you've only got a safety net on this computer, but not any other.  So retraining your brain to think ahead is a better long-term solution.

Comment: I disagree with your premise: *`"retraining your brain to think ahead is a better long-term solution"`*, but your answer is OK   :)    +1

Comment: @Seamus If we want to get things done by programming computers, the first and most powerful one is in our heads.

Comment: @benwiggy: agreed, all I meant by the comment was that thinking ahead is an admirable objective, but can also get us into a pickle; i.e. we fool ourselves.